# Using List & Label browser plugins or ActiveX controls to preview in an ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, plugins, listlabel

I am using combit list & label reporting software for one of my program in asp.net , unfortunately every thing is working but unable to preview the label before printing .

I have tried to manually import the created labels in to the path location from where it will fetch the label images , but even after it is not working , showing as plugin is available and when i right click on that arer it shows 3 options first is  - install plugins which is greyed out unable to use it , second one is hide and third one is inspect element(i am using windows app to create the label and then fetch it in the web forms , while searching for the previously saved label in the windows app it opens automatically with out any probelm)

```
CabFilePath = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["CabFilePath"].ToString();
LblFilePath =  
ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["LblFilePath"].ToString();
```

the above code fetches the label form the path
How or Were to check the required plugins in the source

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET, it is strongly suggested to use the List & Label HTML5 viewer. The technology you're describing is outdated, as most browser vendors have stopped to support plugins that use DLL calls and ActiveX controls for security reasons. The documentation for using the HTML5 viewer is [here](https://docu.combit.net/net/en/Use%20the%20HTML5-Viewer.html). A sample page that uses the HTML5 viewer for demonstration purposes is [here](https://www.combit.com/reporting-tool/list-label-online-demo/).