# unable to view preview in chrome for combit list and label

Tags: listlabel

[image]I am using combit list and label for printing lables and using combit viewer for previewing. The issue i am facing is i am able to preview the labels in IE but it showing the plugin is not supported in chrome.More over on inspecting it is not showing any plugin to install but prompting to hide the plugin.

pls guide .
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The browser vendors got more and more restrictive about enabling plugins. NPAPI plugins are no longer supported since Chrome 45, usage of the preview plugins for Chrome, Firefox and Opera is deprecated, unfortunately.

The suggested way to handle this with List & Label is using the [HTML5 viewer control](https://docu.combit.net/net/en/webframe.html#Use%20the%20HTML5-Viewer.html) that was introduced a couple of years ago.

Comment: Actually, we had this chat before ;): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54021849/using-list-label-browser-plugins-or-activex-controls-to-preview-in-an-asp-net

Comment: thanks for the clarification @JBartlau - whether combit is taking any steps for a new plugin in chrome . and is there any separate forum were can i tutorials about LL designer . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately no, we decided to go platform and browser independent using the HTML5 viewer approach. To answer your question - while SO is an excellent platform we also have a forum at https://forum.combit.net/. On https://support.combit.net/en/reporting-tool/stackoverflow/ you can find a decision helper which place could be the best to get questions answered. Looking forward to hearing from you!

Comment: thanks for the info , i shall keep in touch @JBartlau